# Can't save in Date format Custom default values ​swift

Tags: swift, struct, swiftyuserdefaults

The structure stores the date value in the Date? format, but after saving it returns it in the timestamp format.

```
if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(contact),
     let dict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .Element.fragmentsAllowed) {
            defaults.set(
            dict,
            forKey: "contact")
    }
    print(defaults.object(forKey: "contact"))
}
```

Please tell me how can I save the date in Date format. In this case, it is necessary to preserve the entire structure.

Comment: JSON doesn't support `Date`, Property List does.

Comment: there are alternative options in my case?

Comment: There are `PropertyListEncoder` and `PropertyListSerialization`

Answer (score 0):

As allready pointed out JSON does not support the `Date` type. It will encode it to an integer by default.

But it seems you want to decode it back and use it again as `Date`. This is possible by using the `JSONDecoder()`.

```
let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode("of whatever type the encoded object was here".self, data: data)
```

and you got the same object back that you encoded.

And by the way you don´t need to use `JSONSerialization` to store your object in `UserDefaults` you can store the data directly.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "contact")
```

and retrieving the data:

```
let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "contact")
```

and decoding it like i´ve shown above.